# How to make this a submit button?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a id="submit_signup" class="submit-button button-link" href="">
    <div class="button-container">
        <div class="button-left"></div>
        <div class="button-content">Log in</div>
        <div class="button-right"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

I don't know how to make that a valid submit button.. I have a form and it doesn't redirect to my action! By the way the template is one that I've found on the internets and I'm trying to adapt it. I want a submit button but with the same looks, with the same divs..

Any of you professionals know? I'm 10 and I think I'm very into this :)

The whole form:

```
<form id="register_form" method="post" action="data.php">
    <div class="input-area">
        <h4>Username / Email</h4>
        <input id="id_usermail" type="text" class="text" value="Username or Email" name="id_usermail" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-area">
        <h4>Password</h4>
        <input id="id_password" type="password" class="text" value="password" name="id_password" />
    </div>

    <a id="submit_signup" class="submit-button button-link" href="">
        <div class="button-container">
            <div class="button-left"></div>
            <div class="button-content">Log in</div>
            <div class="button-right"></div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div id="errors" class="errors"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post your form code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `<input type="submit" value="Log in" />`, and style it with CSS.

If you want to use an `<a>` element, you'll need to add some JavaScript. It's simple enough to do with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), but there's no point in relying on JavaScript for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 3):

I'd wrap the whole thing in a `<button>` tag, that should do it. BTW, good for you on being into web devel that early.

**Edit:** @Gareth is right: convert  to  and keep attributes.

Comment: In fact, you'll want to *change* the `<a>` to a `<button>` rather than wrap it (and remove the `href`) for this to work properly

Comment: Well.. when I do that I get the "real button", and under it, the standard white button. Kinda strange..

Comment: can you put it on a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Replace it all by `<input type=submit value="Log in">` or `<button type=submit>Log in</button>`.

The code you found somewhere uses tricky markup to create something button-like from pieces, presumably using backgrounds with CSS and all kinds of code (including code that makes it functionally simulate a submit button) not present in the snippet you included.

Answer (score 0):

you must use  tag and determine action and .. here

```
<form action="target_page">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The idea here is that he wants to keep the same HTML structure. This solution introduces a new input tag.